# Strange error when attempting to update product (GoogleShopping related)

Tags: error, catalog

Modifying simple product in an older version of Magento CE (1.5.0.0).

Not sure what would have brought this on but am getting an error message when I attempt to save:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setConfig() on a non-object in 
/chroot/home/firstaid/firstaidandsafetyonline.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Service.php 
on line 66
```

I attempted to investigate that specific line in the file but couldn't understand why it would have an effect on saving simple products. Here are the surrounding lines:

```
// Create an authenticated HTTP client
        $errorMsg = Mage::helper('googleshopping')->__('Unable to connect to Google Content. Please, check Account settings in configuration.');
        try {
            if (!Mage::registry($this->_clientRegistryId)) {
                $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass,
                    Varien_Gdata_Gshopping_Content::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME, null, '', $loginToken, $loginCaptcha,
                    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, $type
                );
                $configTimeout = array('timeout' => 60);
                $client->setConfig($configTimeout);
                Mage::register($this->_clientRegistryId, $client);
            }
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
            Mage::throwException($errorMsg . Mage::helper('googleshopping')->__('Error: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $e) {
            Mage::throwException($errorMsg . Mage::helper('googleshopping')->__('Error: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        }

        return Mage::registry($this->_clientRegistryId);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We just got this error. ehen we try to go into a product thru the catalog->product, select a product and then go to the inventory tab and click save it gives the error message​  Everything works fine if we edit it from the grid (via an extension.)

Answer (score 2):

I also saw this error on EE 1.13.0.2. As it turns out, my site is using Rocket Web to generate the feed, so I don't need Google Shopping and could disable it. However, this is where my investigation took me...

I checked out system.log and was getting this error:

`ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /ebs/sites/prod/releases/2015-05-28_070414/lib/Zend/Gdata/ClientLogin.php on line 150`

That happens to be the place in the code where I'm getting the API response call from Google. So I logged the response and saw this url as the body of the response... https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

Read that page. For me it meant that my code was super outdated. If you end up in the same place, you probably need to update your lib/Zend/Gdata code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @BobKennedy! I will definitely check that out. Do you think I pursue updating that module or getting the Magento instance upgdated from CE 1.5?

Comment: For me, the problem wasn't the module, but the code in lib/Zend. My coworker says that upgrading Magento is probably the safest way to upgrade Zend. But you could probably get away without upgrading at all. If you don't need Google Shopping, shut it off. If you do need it, see if there's an extension that'll do the same thing with less pain. (RocketWeb is what I'm using)